# How to smooth out edges of circles drawn in canvas with arc?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am drawing circles in a html5 canvas using arc but the edges are rough and not smooth. I am looking to smooth them out. Stacked overflow requires me to write more so my code to text ratio is better

Code

```
(function() {
var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||   window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
}());

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

createCircle(100, 150, '85', '675');
createCircle(300, 150, '70', '479');
createCircle(500, 150, '91', '715');
createCircle(700, 150, '58', '334');


function createCircle(x, y, temp, hash, callback) {
  var radius = 75;
  var endPercent = parseInt(temp, 10);
  var curPerc = 0;
  var counterClockwise = false;
  var circ = Math.PI * 2;
  var quart = Math.PI / 2;

  context.strokeStyle ='#006600';
  context.lineWidth = 10;
  context.lineCap = "round";
  var offset = quart;

function doText(context, x, y, temp, hash) {
    context.lineWidth = 10;  
    if(parseInt(temp, 10) > 90)
        context.fillStyle = '#ad2323';
    else if(parseInt(temp, 10) > 82)
        context.fillStyle = '#ffcc33';
    else
        context.fillStyle = '#006600';

    context.font = "28px sans-serif";
    context.fillText(temp + 'º', x - 20, y + 10);
    context.fillText(hash + 'KH/s', x - 50, y - 90);
}

function animate(current) {
    context.lineWidth = 10;
    if(curPerc > 89)
        context.strokeStyle = '#ad2323';
    else if(curPerc > 81)
        context.strokeStyle = '#ffcc33';

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, offset, ((circ) * current) + offset , false);
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();      
    curPerc++;
    if (curPerc < endPercent) {
       requestAnimationFrame(function () {
            animate(curPerc / 100);
        });
    } 
    else {
        doText(context, x, y, temp, hash);
        if (callback) callback.call();
    }
 }
 animate();
}
```

JSFiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/uhVj6/712/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are drawing strokes multiple times so they are drawing over one another. You need to clear the area where the old arc stroke was and then draw the new one

```
context.clearRect(x - radius - context.lineWidth, 
                  y - radius - context.lineWidth, 
                  radius * 2 + (context.lineWidth*2), 
                  radius * 2 + (context.lineWidth*2));
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, radius, offset, ((circ) * current) + offset , false);
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhVj6/717/)

Comment: +1 clearRect will cure the "jaggies" but your answer breaks the questioners design.  Some refactoring is required.

Comment: so the overlap of the strokes was causing the rough edges. to solve this you clear out the space where the new stroke is about to be drawn?

Comment: Im trying to visual what area your clearing using http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_arc.asp

Comment: @markE, could you expand on how it breaks the design, I don't do much in the way of canvas drawing so breaking something with it would be easy for me to do without noticing

Comment: @ElliotWeil, what is being cleared is the area that each arc takes up, so the rectangle being used is one that goes from the top left to the bottom right of each arc.

Comment: so after every stroke we clearing the area that covers one complete circle?

Comment: @ElliotWeil yea, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhVj6/721/) it draws a rectangle over each area that is cleared. So through each loop of the animation it will clear the area that the rectangle encompasses and then draws the new arc.